# Get "Cannot call a class as a function" when importing 2 css files in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am running ReactJS with Server-Side-Render on ASP.Net MVC. I also setup Webpack config. This code of my component works just fine:

```
import "../fine-uploader/fine-uploader.min.css";
```

But when I import another stylesheet, like this:

```
import "../fine-uploader/fine-uploader.min.css";
import "../../Content/fine-uploader/fine-uploader-custom.css";
```

It returns this error when opening the page with my component:

```
TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
   at _classCallCheck -> function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I've to manually restart the Webpack build script command everytime I import something new. I get this error because I've been relying on the webpack-subresource-integrity to watches for changes and rebuild.